# Use geo_point data type on field in _reindex api

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have index that contains two fields: longitude and latitude that are stored as float. I want to create new index and copy data from the first one but with different mappings. I use reindex api with elastic processors which can rename fields and give them different data types. When i try to create field with type "geo_point" it fails.

```
"type": "parse_exception",
       "reason": "[type] type [geo_point] not supported, cannot convert field.",
```

but when i create new index i am able to create field with "geo_point" type.
i tried different workarounds but documentation says that with geo queries you can only use "geo_point" type.
is there any solution?

```
{
  "description": "test pipe",
  "processors": [
    {
      "convert": {
        "field": "location", 
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

added pipe definition.

Comment: Please show your ingest pipeline definition

Comment: sorry for being so late:)
added pipeline definition.

Comment: Can you also show your mapping and a sample document, please?

Comment: Basically the problem is that this pipe is not valid, kibana shows error, meaning that any field can not be converted to geo_point type. Error happens when i want to create this pipe.

Comment: Do you actually have a field called `location`? Can you show what the pipeline creation error is?

Comment: it doesn't matter if you have such field until you use a pipeline. I can't event create it.

Comment: Of course it matters. the pipeline cannot create a field out of nowhere. You need to create it from latitude and longitude

Comment: can you please show how it should be?

Comment: Show me a sample document from your index and its mapping and I'll show you how to create your new index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's say that your current index mapping looks like this:

```
PUT oldindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "latitude": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "longitude": {
          "type": "float"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You need to create a new index with the proper mapping, as follows

```
PUT newindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then, you can simply leverage the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) to copy the old index into the new one with some additional scripting to create the location field:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "oldindex",
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "newindex"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.location = ['lat': ctx._source.latitude, 'lon': ctx._source.longitude]; ctx._source.remove('latitude'); ctx._source.remove('longitude'); "
  }
}
```

And you're good to go with the location field in your new shiny index!

Comment: Thanks for a comment!The problem is that i cannot execute geo queries on this field, elastic says that it's not geo_point data type.

Comment: which field?, if you create a new index, the field is properly mapped

Comment: Thank you for help man.It was right solution.Sorry for answering with such big intervals.!)

Comment: Great, many thanks. Still works as above on 7.14 ^